# Adding a "All" option into a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble trying to add an "all" option into a dropdown list (fully made in php).
Here's the code:

```
// SLA list
$sql_loc = "SELECT id, name AS name FROM glpi_slas ".$entidade_sw." 
            ORDER BY `name` ASC ";

$result_loc = $DB->query($sql_loc);

$arr_sla = array();
$arr_sla[0] = "-- ". __('Select a SLA', 'dashboard') . " --" ;

while ($row_result = $DB->fetch_assoc($result_loc))     
{ 
    $v_row_result = $row_result['id'];
    $arr_sla[$v_row_result] = $row_result['name'] ;         
} 

$name = 'sel_sla';
$options = $arr_sla;
$selected = $id_sla;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: The "all" options is simply selecting all of the query results, instead of one (as it is right now). Then, the results would not be limitated to only one SLA.

**Edit:** What should I do in order to the option 'Select SLA1' show all the tickets? (Those whose ID can be from 1 to the last possible [5, in that case])

**Edit 2:** This is the code that selects the tickets:

```
    $sql_cham = 
"SELECT glpi_tickets.id AS id, glpi_tickets.name AS descr, glpi_tickets.date AS date, glpi_tickets.solvedate as solvedate, 
glpi_tickets.status, glpi_tickets.due_date AS duedate, sla_waiting_duration AS slawait, glpi_tickets.type,
FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `glpi_tickets`.`solvedate` ) , '%Y-%m' ) AS date_unix, AVG( glpi_tickets.solve_delay_stat ) AS time,
TIMEDIFF(glpi_tickets.atdate, glpi_tickets.solvedate) AS realtime
FROM glpi_tickets
WHERE glpi_tickets.slas_id = ".$id_sla."
AND glpi_tickets.is_deleted = 0
AND glpi_tickets.date ".$datas2."
AND glpi_tickets.status IN ".$status."
".$entidade."

GROUP BY id DESC
ORDER BY id DESC ";
```

Comment: Do you have a row with an ID with value 0? That would override your 'all' option.

Comment: Are you sure `$DB->fetch_assoc($result_loc)` is correct? Might be `$result_loc->fetch_assoc()`. This depends on your framework

Comment: Alex, it's been working so far. The results are shown as they should be.
And moorscode, no I don't have. Should I?

Comment: Please check var_dump() after your while-loop. If it shows a $arr_sla[0] correctly, the problem is later in creating your html from $options.

Comment: Well, it shows "$arr_sla[0]", as it should. Then, creating the html table will be a problem, since there is no html code for that in the file, and it could potentially go wrong.

Comment: mysql ID (if autoIncrement) are `>0` so your $arr_sla[0] should work...

Comment: `What should I do in order to the option 'Select SLA1' show all the tickets` => we need the query that get back the ticket byID or the displaying/filter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Be Careful, your/this SQL is not secure again SQL injection**

use this :

```
"WHERE glpi_tickets.slas_id LIKE ".(empty($id_sla)?'"%"':$id_sla)."
-- instated of this
-- WHERE glpi_tickets.slas_id = ".$id_sla."
```

Comment: That is about the injection, or does it include a solution for my question?
Thanks, anyway.

Comment: it's the solution; without the security you **SHOULD** have to add

Comment: Okay, then. Thanks for the help!
I'll see the vulnerabilty problem later, since it is a closed system (only the company people have access to it).
Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @JoãoGabrielColi ok if it's a closed system, but still be careful; If this `LIKE ".(empty($id_sla)?'"%"':$id_sla)."` work for you, don't forget to validate the answer to flag your question as solved ;)

Comment: Okay, Blag! I had to delete an if statement that was after the codes I sent, and know it is working! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, nice ;) For later, know `LIKE` allow you to use special char as `%` (full joker) an `_` (single Char joker) ; and `empty($var)?'valTrue' : 'valFalse'` is a ternary test (a small IF/ELSE) to check a var and return a val